# Receive Notification for background/ closed app using FCM not working as per Google Docs

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending notification using FCM which I receive when the app is in foreground/background. When in foreground , the click on notification works as needed. But when the app is in backgorund and we click on notification, it just launches the MainActivity/ Launcher Activity and nothing happens after that. I don't receive as data in getIntent().getExtras(). Also, its not hitting my onMessageReceived() override function also.

Can you please provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onMessageReceived` is not called when the app is closed. Instead, the data is passed in an Intent in your starting activity. Handle the notification click there.

To find out what your starting activity is, check your AndroidManifest.xml file. It will look like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to resolve this. My launcher activity was different. A splash screen was appearing before Main activity. So I had to handle extras there. It worked in that way